# Updating a PostgreSQL table with a unique constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a unique constraint

```sql
CREATE temp TABLE tmp (
    c1 int,
    c2 text,
    c3 int,
    UNIQUE (c2, c3)
);

insert into tmp (c1, c2, c3)
values  (1, 'a', 2),
        (2, 'a', 1)
```

Is it possible to run the update below without getting a unique contraint violation and without modifying table `tmp`?

```sql
update tmp
set c3 = c1
where 1=1
```

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tmp_c2_c3_key". Detail: Key (c2, c3)=(a, 1) already exists.
```

Comment: You want to update the table without updating it and you want to violate the unique constraint without violating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 updates, one that will change your c3 values with other value than then previous ones like

```
UPDATE tmp
SET c3 = -c1
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

and then update your c3 value with the good one

```
UPDATE tmp
SET c3 = c1
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

It will work if all your values in c1 and c3 are positive

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run the update below without getting a unique contraint violation and without modifying table tmp?

No, this is not possible. You would have to make the `UNIQUE` constraint `DEFERRABLE`:

```
    ...
    UNIQUE (c2, c3) DEFERRABLE
    ...
```

Then you could [set it to deferred](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) like this

```
SET CONSTRAINTS tmp_c2_c3_key DEFERRED;
```

and run your update command without a violation error. Note that you must use a transaction for `SET CONSTRAINTS` to work.

Comment: _Defining_ the constraint as deferrable is already enough. There is no need to run `set constraints` to make it work. https://dbfiddle.uk/-73M93wA

Comment: This is not possible because PostGreSQL violate rule 7 of Codd's 12 rules. PostGreSQL updates each row one by one. 
When modifying a row, PG verify the costraints that applies to the updates columns, which is far to be a relationnal behaviour that rely on set based data manipulation.
All other RDBMS (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server...) are compliant with this rule and does not need deferrable constraints to do so.
Deferrable constraints induces much more trouble in logic and blocking, that problems its solved (Chris Date says in "SQL and the relationnal Theory, a coleague of Codd for RDBMS at IBM).

Answer (score 0):

Drop the unique constraint, do your update, reinstate the constraint.